# ISAPI redirect to external site in IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, iis-6, isapi, isapi-rewrite

I'm using [ISAPI Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) and my server is running IIS 6. I've never used ISAPI Rewrite before, so I'm a bit in the dark about how to use it.

I'm trying to do a simple redirect, so that if anyone hits

> http://www.mysite.com/page.aspx

on my server, they are redirected to

> http://externalsite.com/dir/file.htm

which is an external site that isn't mine. Is there a way to do this, or a tutorial that will show me how? I can't find anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous tutorials on this module. You can use these links for the beginning:

- [Exploding myths about mod_rewrite. Part I](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/exploding-myths-about-mod_rewrite-part-i/)
- [Exploding myths about mod_rewrite. Part 2.](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/exploding-myths-about-mod_rewrite-part-2/)
- [Helicon Ape - mod_rewrite documentation](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/mod_rewrite.htm)
- [ISAPI_Rewrite examples](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/examples.htm)

Besides ISAPI_Rewrite, Helicon Ape and mod_rewrite are different products rewrite syntax is the same, so you can use documentation for either product.

For the redirect you are asking I guess it should be the following rule in the www.mysite.com .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page.aspx http://externalsite.com/dir/file.htm [NC, R]
```